# javascript shapes drawing - HOW Raphael's library works in detail? (no <canvas>)

Tags: javascript, drawing, raphael, shapes

Recently i found the raphael's library which is amazing.
For example this:

[Raphael Chart -Demo](http://raphaeljs.com/ichart.html)

When I checked the code I was shocked(in a positive way).

It didn't used HTML5 canvas or any extra divs like [here](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm) (which a don't like)

My question is: How exactly this works in detail? Is pixel manipulation? What is the basic rendering code?

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primarily it uses [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) which is an XML-like markup to represent vectors. For < IE9 browsers, I think it uses [VML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language) which is a deprecated vector mark-up that IE still supports.

SVG/VML are forms of [vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics). They shapes represented by mathematical formulas. This makes them suitable for scalable graphics since formulas recalculated when scaled, maintaining sharp edges, unlike [raster graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics) which pixelate.

Comment: Prior to IE#9 it used VML. In 9, finally it's using a limited version of SVG.

Comment: @boyd libraries like these normalize features to work across browsers. The example you have is SVG, which is [not supported in IE8 and older](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)

Answer (score -1):

Inspect the source with firebug or Chrome's inspector. It generates [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svg).